# Troubleshooting kubernetes nginx controller routing

Tags: kubernetes

I can't get the nginx controller to route based on the hostname.  The YAML below doesn't work - traffic goes to the default back-end / I get a 404.  However, if I remove the value for host, the ingress controller successfully routes traffic to my-service.  The service works successfully if I place it behind a load balancer but I want to have multiple services working for different host names so I want to use an ingress controller and use a single IP.  Thoughts?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test1.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Is traffic over SSL or plain connection?

Answer (score 0):

The yaml looks slightly different than the rewrite example located [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md). The yaml is valid and kubectl apply or create should work but not produce the results you are expecting. Do you need the rewrite annotation or could you remove it and the back end service will respond without issue? If you don't need to rewrite anything try removing the yaml to just look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test1.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```